# What do i need to make my Rasberry Pi 4B a GPS?

Tags: gps, software-compatibility

I have read a little about GPS modules and IMU modules but was wondering how I know what I need to enable my raspberry Pi to have GPS capabilities. I am asking because I put the Emteria software on and downloaded a birding app but the birding app doesn't work correctly due to not getting GPS signal. Any suggestions would be wonderful

Comment: my suggestion is that you clarify what the exact problem is

Comment: Do you have any GPS receiver hardware? Like a Ublox M8.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a good question, and the OP hasn't responded to any of the comments.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

[GPS (Global Positioning System)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) is a system enabled by a constellation of satellites; it requires a receiver to take advantage of the signals broadcast by the satellites. In other words, if you don't have a GPS receiver connected to your RPi, it will not have "GPS capabilities".

And so, what you need is a GPS receiver. They are available in a variety of sizes, shapes, weights and degrees of performance. One GPS unit made as a "breakout board" is available from Adafruit; there are [several others available](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RPi+GPS+module&t=newext&atb=v369-1&ia=web). You may also need an external antenna.